Camera driver not read after modification
I am trying to make some changes based on the parsed addresses of the camera drivers (.bin files) on my Xiaomi device running Android 14. For example, the operating frequency of a certain sensor mode or something. The values in the parsed excel file match the hex values of the driver. But the problem is that even a 1 byte change causes the camera to disappear from the system (I think the driver is not read), while a modified version of the same driver by another developer works as it should. What I want to know is there some kind of mechanism that checks the hash values of these drivers or the file creation dates? Maybe some kind of CRC verification etc.

Yes a CRC is likely. However you forgot to present more details on the file format of the .bin files. In the end IMHO this question is more suitable for https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com

Now I looked at the section you mentioned and yes, this is a more appropriate topic there. As for .bin files, these are simply Qualcomm Chromatix binaries written in C.

Hi, I noticed the request to migrate this to [reverseengineering.se], but as of current writing, I'm afraid it still lacks detail to be answered objectively (as per Robert's comment), and might be closed after migrated (and thus returned back here). I'd recommend posting a new question with more details (including your comment in the question body) directly on that site instead.
